# How to properly return a Pointer from a function to another function?

Tags: c++, pointers

I was writing a small program using pointers,
This is my code:

```
    #include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct number
{
int data;
number *next;
} test;

number * last_node(number *head)
{
    number *temp = new number;
    temp = head;

    while (temp->next != nullptr)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return temp;

}

void insert_at_end (number *head)
{
    number *temp = new number;
    number *last = new number;
last = last_node(*head);

    cout<<"Enter the data";
    cin>>temp->data;
    temp->next = nullptr;
    last->next = temp;
}

void view_all (number *head)
{
    number *temp = new number;
    temp = head;

    while (temp->next != nullptr)
    {
        cout<<temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    number *head = &test;
    int choice;
    char ans = 'y';

    do
    {



    cout<<"Enter your choice";
    cout<<"\n 1. Insert ";
    cout<<"\n 2. View ";
    cout<<"\n 3. Exit ";

    cin>>choice;

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1 : insert_at_end(head);
        break;

        case 2 : view_all(head);
        break;

        case 3 : goto label;

        default : cout<<"You have entered wrong choice";
    }

    cout<<"Do you want the menu again ? (y/n)" ;
    cin>>ans;

    }

    while (ans = 'y');

    label:

        return 0;
}
```

On compilation, an error occurs on saying it can't convert "number" to "number*" while calling the function 'last_node(*head)'.

Can you please help me understand this properly?

Comment: `operator*` is for dereferencing, thus if `head` is a `number*` then `*head` is a `number`

Comment: In `last = last_node(*head);` you are dereferencing `head`, and passing `number`, while `last_node` expects to receive `number*`. In addition, you leak memory in the following statements `number *temp = new number; temp = head;` (because you overwrite pointer to newly allocated `number`). Consider reading [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0):

You've made a few mistakes but straight up front about that error, you just need to pass `head` pointer rather than `*head` which is dereferencing it. There are several memory leaks like inside `last_node()` function you've done -

```
number *temp = new number;
temp = head;
```

creating a new `number` type on heap and pointing that memory to `temp` pointer. Now on the very next line you change `temp` to point to `head`, thus making your `new number` lost. Also while iterating your linked list, you're missing the very last element so look at the modifications I've made. Another critical error is assignment operation instead of `==` here - `while (ans = 'y');`, be careful with these typos. And don't use `goto` where it doesn't fit.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct number {
    int data = 0;
    number *next = nullptr;
};

number *last_node(number *head)
{
    number *temp = head;
    while (temp->next != nullptr) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return temp;
}

void insert_at_end(number *head)
{
    number *temp = new number();
    number *last = last_node(head);

    cout << "Enter the data";
    cin >> temp->data;
    temp->next = nullptr;
    last->next = temp;
}

void view_all(number *head)
{
    number *temp = head;
    while (temp != nullptr) {
        cout << temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    number *head = new number();
    int choice;
    char ans = 'y';

    do {
        cout << "Enter your choice";
        cout << "\n 1. Insert ";
        cout << "\n 2. View ";
        cout << "\n 3. Exit ";

        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice) {
            case 1: insert_at_end(head); break;
            case 2: view_all(head); break;
            case 3: return 0;
            default: cout << "You have entered wrong choice";
        }

        cout << "Do you want the menu again ? (y/n)";
        cin >> ans;
    }
    while (ans == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```